# jQuery - Data-table does not keep column width after sorting

Tags: jquery, css, datatable, column-width

I have a jQuery data-table which I specified the column width likes following:

```
"aoColumnDefs":[
  { "sWidth":"40%" },
  { "sWidth":"10%" },
  { "sWidth":"50%" } ]
```

I also specified the CSS style like:

```
  td { position: relative, word-wrap: break-word; }
```

The table displays exactly as I wanted, long entries have been wrapped.  However, when I sorted on the second column (the sorting is handled by the back-end server), some of the values of the first column are long but never broke and wrapped. The table showed only one column (due to the longest length of the value exceeded the table width).

How can I get the data-table obey the initialized width and render correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the `sClass` property of the cells in that column to style go here http://datatables.net/ref and scroll down the the sClass reference.

```
"aoColumnDefs":[
  { "sWidth":"40%", "sClass":"relative-postition-and-break-word" },
  { "sWidth":"10%", "sClass":"relative-postition-and-break-word" },
  { "sWidth":"50%", "sClass":"relative-postition-and-break-word" } ]
```

(The long class name is just to get the point across as to what your class would have as css)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I already have a SClass in place, which defined as 'word-wrap: break-word;' but it did not work.  I'll try 'relative position'.